# upgraded API package from netcore2.2 to Net6.0, after that swagger is not loading

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api, swagger-ui

receiving the below error on http://localhost:53363/swagger/v1/swagger.json, the documentation.xml file is generating but i hope swagger() is not loading into json.

> {"Code":"UnhandledException","Messages":["The constraint reference 'apiVersion' could not be resolved to a type. Register the constraint type with 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteOptions.ConstraintMap'."],"InnerError":null}

i used this,

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {


        app.UseExceptionHandler(CommonExceptionHandling.HandleError());
        app.UseHsts();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors(corsKey);
        app.UseRouting();

        
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            
        });

       app.UseSwagger();
       app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "V1");
            c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
        });        
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

    }
```

Comment: Why do you have `app.UseRouting();` several times? Also the middleware order is quite strange.